# Equivalent actions with normalizing element

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $x \in G$, $G$ a group, $H$ a subgroup of G, and $G$ acts on a set $X$. Then if $x$ normalizes $H$, I know that we can say that $x$ permutes the orbits of $H$ on $X$.

How can we prove that if $\theta$ is an $H$-orbit and $x\theta$ is its image, then the actions of $H$ on $\theta$ and $x\theta$ are equivalent? I am not sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the equivalent actions? One of the possible definitions is the following:

Let $G$ act on two sets $A$ and $B$. These actions are called equivalent if there
is a bijection $f : A \to B$ such that $f(g.a) = g.f(a)$ for all $g ∈ G$ and $a ∈ A$.

Now we have an action of $H$ on the orbit $A=\theta$. Let $B=x.\theta=\{x.p\mid p\in\theta\}$. Then we can define the action of $H$ on $B$ in the following way: $h\cdot (x.p)=(xhx^{-1}).(x.p)$. Here '$.$' denotes the 'old' action of the whole group $G$ on $X$, and '$\cdot$' is our new action of $H$ on the set $B$. One checks that it is really an action.

Now if we set $f\colon A\to B$, $a\mapsto x.a$, we will get for all $h\in H$:
$$
f(h.a)=h\cdot f(a).
$$
which is the condition for the equivalence of two actions. It remains to show that $f:A\to B$ is a bijection. Surjectivity is by the construction of $B=x.\theta$, and injectivity is a one-liner computation.